# When will Uber Pool be added to the Uber Developers API?

Tags: uber-api

As the question says, when will the Uber Developers API support Uber Pool?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but this is off topic here. Uber API related questions are welcome, but they need to be strictly programming related rather than be about Uber's policies and possible future developments.

Comment: The only way to reach Uber Developers Support is via StackOverflow so I assumed this would be a good fit since I'm assuming a lot of developers are wondering when will this be added. Thanks.

Comment: I see. If you were redirected here from Uber and they gave you the impression that this is the go-to place for *all* Uber API questions, could you post the URL of the page in question? Perhaps someone from the SO team can reach out and talk to them about making the wording more clear.

Comment: The URL is: https://developer.uber.com/support/ - Under "Check out the forum". Sending an email to them (under Still need Help?) below results in an email reply from them after a few days directing you to StackOverflow: "Thanks for your inquiry. We currently use StackOverflow to support developers with Uber API questions. Please post your question to StackOverflow with the `uber-api` tag and a member of our team will respond shortly." I will try to contact them in other ways anyway - thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update (5/3/2016): uberPOOL in the API will launch on 5/9/2016. Check out the documentation for a preview of the changes: https://developer.uber.com/docs/tutorials-rides-api#section-uberpool

Comment: Thanks for answering. It sounds like you might be with Uber? Would you mind disclosing that in your profile? Also, did you see [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36205107/when-will-uber-pool-be-added-to-the-uber-developers-api?noredirect=1#comment60043674_36205107)? It would help if your support page clarified where to ask meta questions about Uber API. (Hint: [SO is not the place](http://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support). ;)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I updated my profile to disclose that I'm with Uber. We'll work with the team on how to support meta questions.